# Python - Accessing columns of a Panda Dataframe effectively

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was working with Python Pandas for quite a while and now staring at the two commands below thinking what would be the difference between both.

```
df1['Col1']          #Shows only the values of 'Col1' from df1 dataframe.
df1[['Col1','Col2']] #Shows the values of both 'Col1' and 'Col2' from df1 dataframe.
```

My question is when we are able to access a column with the help of single square brackets ('[ ]'), why can't we do the same for accessing multiple columns. I tried with the below command and encountered error.

```
df1['Col1','Col2']   #Encountered error
```

Comment: I think `df1[['Col1','Col2']]` is short way of `df1.loc[:, ['Col1','Col2']]` - select columns by `list`. And why  `df1['Col1','Col2']` does not work - simpliest answer is because it is not implemented this way in pandas.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for your response. But still I do not understand the actual reason behind the existence of df1['Col1']

Comment: Hmmm, `df1['Col1']` is select column to `Series`. If want select column with output one column df, need `df1[['Col1']]` - it is `one element list`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

---

In python, `[]` is syntactic sugar for the `__getitem__` method.

This:

```
df['col1']

0    1
1    3
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Is equivalent to:

```
df.__getitem__('col1')

0    1
1    3
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

And this:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']]

   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
```

Is the same as this:

```
df.__getitem__(['col1', 'col2'])

   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
```

---

**So....** when you do this

```
df['col1', 'col2']
```

It's trying to force whatever is there into a single argument and it's the same as

```
df.__getitem__(('col1', 'col2'))
```

Which gets you

> KeyError: ('col1', 'col2')

Comment: Sir thats indepth. :)

Answer (score 3):

Usually pandas take one index value while selecting the data using `[]` . Either pass the one column name or pass a  list of columns names as one. When you pass two value it will be treated that as a tuple and will search for the same in the dataframe. There are cases tuples are used as column names. Thats the reason why there will be a key error.

You can have a column name like `df['Col1','Col2'] = 'x'` then this `df['Col1','Col2']` will work. To avoid this kind of ambugity there is a need of passing column names more than one as a list.

Comment: Good one @Bharath shetty