# How to resolve date time error in Pandas code?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has 7 columns `['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']`
The thing is I tried to set a datetime index but it does not work may be because date and time are two separate columns.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

column_names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low','Close', 'Volume']

df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Tutorial\EURUSD60.csv", header=None, names=column_names)

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date', 'Time'])

print(df.head())
```

Here is the error:

> C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\python.exe E:/Tutorial/language.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2442, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: ('Date',
>   'Time')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/Tutorial/language.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date', 'Time'])   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 1964, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 1971, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 1645, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 3590, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)   File "C:\Users\sydgo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2444, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: ('Date',
>   'Time')

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483409/4800652 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify your code,  you'll see the error is right here:

```
df['Date', 'Time']
```

That's because you are indexing into the DataFrame once by two strings, but you want to index into it twice, by each of two strings.  That is:

```
df[['Date', 'Time']]
```

Still, this may fail, because `to_datetime` expects strings, not pairs of strings:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date', 'Time'])
```

In which case try this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time)
```